# almost surely convergence to zero of indicator function

Tags: measure-theory

How can we show that: if $x$ is an integrable function (i.e., $\int_X|x|<\infty$), and $\{S_m\}$ is a sequence in $\Sigma$ ($\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$) in $X$ such that $\mu(S_m)\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$, where $\mu$ is a finite measure defined over $\Sigma$, then 
$$\int_{S_m}|x|\,\mathrm{d}\mu\to 0.$$
Can anyone give me some ideas? Many thanks. (I think the core is to show that $|x|\cdot 1_{S_m}$ converges to $0$ almost surely, but I don't know how to show that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the conditions, it's not necessarily true that $|x| 1_{S_m}$ converges to $0$ almost surely.

Here is one way to solve the problem: Fix $N>0$. You can partition $X$ into $X_N$, the set where $|x|\le N$, and $X'_N$, the set where $|x|>N$.  The integral of $|x|$ over $S_m\cap X_N$ is bounded by $N \mu(S_m)$, and the integral of $|x|$ over $X'_N$ must approach $0$ as $N\to\infty$ because $x$ is integrable.  Then, let $N\to\infty$ as $m\to\infty$ at an appropriate rate.

Comment: What does *Then, let $N\to\infty$ as $m\to\infty$ at an appropriate rate* mean?

Comment: It means to construct a function $N(m)$ such that $\lim_{m\to\infty} N(m)=\infty$ and such that $\lim_{m\to\infty} {\cal B}(N(m),m)=0$, where ${\cal B}(N,m)$ is the bound outlined above.

Comment: Such as $N(m)=$ the integer part of $1/\sqrt{\mu(S_m)}$? I see, thanks.

Comment: One more question: How can we show that if x is integrable, then the integral of |x| over $X'_N$ goes to zero?(intuitive, but I don't know how to put it rigorously) Thanks!

Comment: Use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: I only came up with this method: $\int_X |x|\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{E_n}|x|\,d\mu<\infty$, where $E_n=\{n-1\le |x|< n\}$.And hence by Cauchy Criterion we have $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=m}\int_{E_n}|x|\,d\mu=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{E_m}|x|\,d\mu\to 0$. How to apply dominated convergence theorem here, I mean what is the limit of $|x|\cdot 1_{E_n}$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that method works as well.  What I had in mind was: $1_{X'_N} |x|\to 0$ a.e. as $N\to\infty$ ∴ $\int_{X'_N} |x| d\mu \to 0$.

Comment: This is what I intended to do first, but I met a trouble to put it clearly that $|x|\cdot 1_{X'_N}\to 0$ almost everywhere. Would you please give me some more guidance? Thank you very much!

Comment: Since $x$ is integrable, the subset of $X$ on which $|x|=+\infty$ has measure $0$, so you can ignore it.  Fix some point in $X$ not in this subset.  Then, $|x|$ has a finite value, and when $N$ exceeds this value, the point is no longer in $X'_N$, so $1_{X'_N} |x| =0$.  Therefore, $1_{X'_N}|x|$ converges to $0$ at this point.

Comment: This is a tremendous help! I really appreciate it! Have a good night!

Comment: @user65018 You might want to upvote this answer since it pleases you.